# C# - What is the purpose of this statement in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, object, initialization

I think I have a fairly basic question here. I'm not trying to waste your time, but I just didn't know what to Google to get a good answer. My question has to do with object initialization. Take the following example from the Head First C# book:

```
using System;
using etc...

namespace Bees
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Queen queenie = new Queen(workers, Report); //Queen is a created class
        }
        Queen queenie; //This is the line I'm curious about

        private void assignButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Report.AppendText(queenie.AssignWork(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), (int)shifts.Value));
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            queenie.WorkNextShift();
        }
...
```

If I've already instantiated a Queen object by saying `Queen queenie = new Queen(...);`, what purpose does the `Queen queenie` line serve, and what is its scope? What key concept am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like a bug in the code. Probably this was meant:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    queenie = new Queen(workers, Report);
}

Queen queenie; //This is where the reference to the constructed Queen is stored
```

The line `Queen queenie;` declares a field of type `Queen` that is accessible from all methods of the instance, but not from outside the class.

If you are uncertain what some of these terms mean, I suggest that you follow a more gentle tutorial:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807574/best-c-sharp-programing-books-for-absolute-beginner-or-someone-just-starting-wit

Or if you already blew your book budget for the year then browse some of the free online documentaition:

- [Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042)
- [Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173110)
- [Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx)
- [Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173113)
- [Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114)
- [Access Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121)

Comment: I'm pretty new. Is there any chance you could explain this in less technical terms?

Comment: @AdamHollander: If you really want to learn the very basics, I think it's better to start with a very simple tutorial. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807574/best-c-sharp-programing-books-for-absolute-beginner-or-someone-just-starting-wit)

Comment: @AdamHollander You can try thenewboston on youtube, he has some great tutorials on programming - http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0EE421AE8BCEBA4A&feature=plcp